# Plotting Point Classes in Java

Tags: java

Could someone please show me some code or a tutorial of how to use Java's libraries to plot Point Class Objects onto a graph and how to join them up with lines and fill in certain areas between the points with colour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend checking out [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) and referring to its examples.

Doing that kind of work by hand is fairly labor-intensive when done correctly.

Answer (score 1):

[JFreeChart](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartLineChartDemo6.htm) is your friend :)

Answer (score -1):

see point2D and line2D documentation

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html

Answer (score -1):

you could take a look at this... i think there's a demo as well

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html

**Update:**

If you don't want to introduce a new dependency you can use what plain old java provides. Inside a component's `paint()` method...

```
  public void paint (Graphics g) {
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      ...
  }
```

... you could use the following Classes for example:

```
// draw Line2D.Double
g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x2, y2));

// draw Point
g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x1, y1));
```

or various other shapes like `QuadCurve2D`, `Rectangle2D`, `Ellipse2D` etc...
If you need to draw polygons (custom shapes with multiple vertices) you can use
`GeneralPath`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I see your point and made some improvements to my answer